# LINQ Queries: Retrieve List using Any

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables. Contact table and a client table. ContactID is a foreign key in client table. 
I have a query that returns a List of contacts. I want a seperate list of all the clients where client.contactid in the first list of contacts. I think i can use Any method just now sure how. Thanks. Using LINQ to EF

```
 List<Contact> contacts = GetContactByCompany().ToList();
```

Have something along the lines of

```
List<Client> = from client in Client.Any(client => contacts.ID.Contains(client.ContactID))
```

Comment: With the given information: Yes, it's quite possible that you could.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking + we don't write code for you if you didn't try a bit

Comment: What is **Client** here `from client in Client` ?

Comment: @IvanStoev client is the model and and is in the DBContext. using EF.

Comment: Any will return true if any result match the criteria and false if not, it will not return the results that match. This can be done using where.

Comment: @luckyluke I was first one to correctly answer your question, but strangely you did not acknowledge, thought you have a different requirement, which was not the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are seeking for something like this

```
var clients = Client.Where(client => contacts.Any(contact => contact.ID == client.ContactID)).ToList();
```

or

```
var contactIds = contacts.Select(contact => contact.ID).ToList();
var clients = Client.Where(client => contactIds.Contains(client.ContactID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

A Possible solution

Fetch a List of Contact Ids from first Contacts list fetched

```
List<int> ContactIdList = ContactList.Where(x=>x.Id).ToList()
```

Fetch All Clients and filter for `ContactId`, which are part of `ContactIds` list fetched above

```
List<Client> FilteredClientList = ClientList.Where(x=>ContactIdList.Contains(x.ContactId)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that you are saying it is EF :(

```
List<Contact> contacts = GetContactByCompany().ToList();
var contactIds = contacts.Select( c => c.ContactID ).Distinct();
var clients = ctx.Clients.Where( c => contactIds.Contains( c.ContactID ) );
```

PS: This wouldn't work beyond parameter count limit for the designated backend (ie: in MS SQL it would work up to 2100 IDs).

Answer (score 0):

```
var clients = contacts.Select( c => c.Client ); // Distinct() may be needed
```

Sampling with the MS SQL server sample database Northwind:

```
var orders = Orders.Where (o => o.ShipCountry == "USA");
var customers = orders.Select (o => o.Customer).Distinct();
```

When customers is materialized (foreach, ToList() ...) this is the SQL sent to server:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) SET @p0 = 'USA'
-- EndRegion
SELECT DISTINCT [t1].[CustomerID], [t1].[CompanyName], [t1].[ContactName], [t1].[ContactTitle], [t1].[Address], [t1].[City], [t1].[Region], [t1].[PostalCode], [t1].[Country], [t1].[Phone], [t1].[Fax]
FROM [Orders] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Customers] AS [t1] ON [t1].[CustomerID] = [t0].[CustomerID]
WHERE [t0].[ShipCountry] = @p0
```

Comment: Client would have the Contact object, not other way around

Comment: It is always two way. I didn't see your edit before. Remove "ToList()" there, else it would be multiple SQL queries sent to server instead of one.